# Viewing PDF annotations in Evince

Tags: gui, pdf, evince

I'm trying to get around a bug in the Evince GUI. Annotations in a PDF are shown with (1) a highlight to the text color, and (2) a small comment-box icon. Clicking the comment-box icon opens a sticky-note with the annotation. Clicking the highlight opens an empty sticky-note with a yellow background. Unfortunately, the z-level of the highlighted text is above that of the comment-box icon. In one case, the hitbox of the highlighted text completely overlaps that of the comment-box icon, so I see no way to open the annotation. Can any Evince gurus describe a way to get around this annoying software flaw? Is there a way to view annotations from the command line? Thanks.